# Unable to install Maven on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation

I'm not able to install maven on my system I have tried using below command:

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

It giving me below errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libperl5.22 : Depends: perl-modules-5.22 (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2) but 5.22.1-9 is to be installed
  maven : Depends: libmaven3-core-java (= 3.3.9-3) but it is not going to be installed
  perl : Depends: perl-modules-5.22 (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2) but 5.22.1-9 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have no clue what happening here and how do I install it.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get install -f` as suggested in the error message? If that doesn't help, could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -f maven`? Thanks.

Comment: @David Foerster, thanks I have tried the command you have mentioned  it resolved my issue. Can you post this as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message suggests “run `apt-get -f install` with no packages”:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If that doesn't help, your packages may be (partially) out of date. Update them while fixing dependency issues again (`-f`):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```

(You can also append `maven` to the latter command to try to install it in one go together with the upgrades and dependency fixes.)

If `apt-get update` leads to errors itself, please try to fix them before you proceed. Search on Ask Ubuntu for the error message<sup>1</sup> or ask a new question.

---

<sup>1</sup> Sometimes Google is a better search engine than the one integrated into Stack Exchange. You can limit a Google search to one domain with the `site:` operator, e. g. `site:askubuntu.com Unmet dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

It might looks dummy but did you run `sudo apt-get -f install` as it recommend?